# Take elements that match from a pair of arrays (C++/OpenCV)

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

I'm using an OpenCV function that takes matching elements from two single channel matrices and gives you a resulting array with only that element. The function is called  [`compare`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare)

```
cv::compare(maskMat, cv::GC_FGD, result, cv::CMP_EQ);
```

`maskMat` is my matrix containing any value from `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`.

`cv::GC_FGD` is just a matrix with each element equal to 1.

`cv::CMP_EQ` is a flag that checks if the two elements are equal.

What I'd also like to take any values of `cv::GC_PR_FGD`, which is `3`. So basically, I wish I do something like `(cv::GC_FGD || cv::GC_PR_FGD)`, taking any element whose value is `1` or `3` for my new resulting matrix.

Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compare function produces an output array with a value set to `255` if the corresponding comparison returns `true`.

What you could do is use a two-step process:
First, perform two individual comparisons to get two arrays with the respective `true` values.
Second, combine the two matrices using a [Matrix Expression](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrixexpressions):

```
cv::Mat result0;
cv::Mat result1;

cv::compare(maskMat, cv::GC_FGD,    result0, cv::CMP_EQ); // Compare for equality to 1.
cv::compare(maskMat, cv::GC_PR_FGD, result1, cv::CMP_EQ); // Compare for equality to 3.

cv::Mat result = cmp0 | cmp1; // Combine the result of the comparisons
                              // by using bit-wise OR.
```

The `bit-wise OR` is a matrix expression that calculates the output matrix by performing the bit-wise operation on the two input matrices. Since the two input matrices are just composed of `0` and `255` values, this effectively creates the output you desire.

You could also replace the `compare` function by the appropriate matrix expressions, which are just `==`:

```
cv::Mat cmp1 = maskMat == 1; // Compare for equality to 1.
cv::Mat cmp3 = maskMat == 3; // Compare for equality to 3.

cv::Mat result = max(cmp0, cmp1); // Combine the result of the comparisons
                                  // by using the max function.
```

The `max` function used above works equally as well as the bit-wise OR in this case.

Since matrix expressions can be arbitrarily combined, you could actually put it all on a single line:

```
cv::Mat result = (maskMat == 1) | (maskMat == 3);
```

Hope that helps!